# Could not find Angular Material core theme. Most Material components may not work as expected

Tags: angular2, angular, angular-material

Я только начинаю изучать ангуляр.
Почему при добавлении в **app.module.ts**:

```
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
...
imports: [
MatToolbarModule
  ]
...
```

В консоли возникает предупреждение: "Could not find Angular Material core theme. Most Material components may not work as expected."
Это нормальная практика при выборочном добавлении материальных компонентов или что-то не так? Может надо подгружать все материал-компоненты?

Здесь есть тысяча ответов на этот вопрос, все сводится к тому что надо импортировать стили prebuild-theme инклудом в style.css или в angular.json с перезагрузкой, но это не помогает от предупреждения. Сам < mat-toolbar > работает.

ng add @angular/material - выбрал custom-theme, в папке src автоматически был создан файл **custom-theme.scss**

```
// Custom Theming for Angular Material
// For more information: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
// Plus imports for other components in your app.

// Include the common styles for Angular Material. We include this here so that you only
// have to load a single css file for Angular Material in your app.
// Be sure that you only ever include this mixin once!
@include mat-core();

// Define the palettes for your theme using the Material Design palettes available in palette.scss
// (imported above). For each palette, you can optionally specify a default, lighter, and darker
// hue. Available color palettes: https://material.io/design/color/
$angular-primary: mat-palette($mat-indigo);
$angular-accent: mat-palette($mat-pink, A200, A100, A400);

// The warn palette is optional (defaults to red).
$angular-warn: mat-palette($mat-red);

// Create the theme object (a Sass map containing all of the palettes).
$angular-theme: mat-light-theme($angular-primary, $angular-accent, $angular-warn);

// Include theme styles for core and each component used in your app.
// Alternatively, you can import and @include the theme mixins for each component
// that you are using.
@include angular-material-theme($angular-theme);
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { HeaderComponent } from './components/header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './components/footer/footer.component';

import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';




@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatToolbarModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**angular.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "angular": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/angular",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": false,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/custom-theme.scss",
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/pink-bluegrey.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "angular:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "angular:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "angular:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/custom-theme.scss",
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/pink-bluegrey.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "angular:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "angular:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "angular"
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44230852/angular-material-could-not-find-angular-material-core-theme . и создай _минимальный воспроизводимый пример_ =)

Comment: Я пока гуглил, раз 10 на ту страницу натыкался. Дополнил вопрос, больше не знаю что выложить

Comment: Нужно не дополнять вопрос, а открыть stackblitz или codesandbox, создать там мини пример и вставить сюда ссылку, чтоб все, кто видели твой вопрос - могли там поиграться с кодом и, возможно, предоставить решение =)